# How to interact with main window while message box is visible?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a problem. I am using Tkinter for a GUI and I have a message box appear. (like a warning or info) The problem is, that you can't interact with the main window once the message box appears, which I have to. How can I interact with both windows at the same time?

This is my code I currently use:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
def answer():
    mb.showerror("Answer", "Sorry, no answer available")

def callback():
    if mb.askyesno('Verify', 'Really quit?'):
        mb.showwarning('Yes', 'Not yet implemented')
    else:
        mb.showinfo('No', 'Quit has been cancelled')

tk.Button(text='Quit', command=callback).pack(fill=tk.X)
tk.Button(text='Answer', command=answer).pack(fill=tk.X)
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The messagebox is designed explicitly to have the behavior you've seen. If you want to display a popup window with a message and still be able to interact with the main window, you'll need to create your own window for the message with `Toplevel`.